# How can I show the date a file or folder was created?

Tags: nautilus

I really need date created for folders/files. As far as I can see, this is not possible at present. Just an option in preferences of given file manager will suffice. Anybody?

Answer (score -1):

There is no creation time for a file. It isn't stored anywhere. Files have a last-modified time and last-accessed time that can be presented in the files manager.
There is though an inode change time that is often referred to as the "creation time" but that's not accurate as some activities (like backup) will modify this date.

Comment: Ext4 does indeed keep records of creation time and so do other file systems. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40093/22222) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/470134/85695).