# How do I find the creation time of a file?

Tags: filesystem, metadata, stat

I need  to find the creation time of a file, when I read some articles about this issue, all mentioned that there is no solution (like [Site1](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-do-i-find-out-when-a-directory-was-created-236863/), [Site2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file)).

When I tried the `stat` command, it states  `Birth: -`.

So how can I find the creation time of a file?

Comment: Keep in mind that the 'creation time' of a file is not guaranteed to be accurate.  There are many ways to 'fudge' the creation dates on a file.

Comment: @ThomasWard Many more than ways to fudge other file data?

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304779

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There is a way to know the creation date of a directory , just follow these steps :

1. Know the **inode** of the directory by `ls -i` command (lets say for example its **X**)
2. Know on which partition your directory is saved  by `df -T /path` command ( lets say its on  `/dev/sda1` )
3. Now use this command : `sudo debugfs -R 'stat <X>' /dev/sda1`

You will see in the output :

```
crtime: 0x4e81cacc:966104fc -- mon Sep 27 14:38:28 2013
```

**crtime**  is the creation date of your file .

**What I tested** :

1. Created a directory at specific time .
2. Accessed it .
3. Modified it by creating a file .
4. I tried the command and it gave an exact time .
5. Then i modify it , and test again , the **crtime** remained  the same ,
   but **modify** and **access** time changed .

Comment: I post this , because i like to discuss so i can understand better , i am wonder why people say that Linux doesn't support this feature

Comment: Because Linux itself does not. The ext4 filesystem does have this information but the kernel does  not provide an API to access it. Apparently, `debugfs` extracts it directly from the filesystem so it does not need to use the kernel's API. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50184/22222).

Comment: I tested it. It worked perfectly on ext4 file system

Comment: Seems like this is ext4 specific? It didn't work with XFS for me.

Comment: The kernel, glibc, and coreutils all now support `statx()` as of March 2019.

Comment: @hippietrail do you have the version numbers?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor `statx(), available on glibc >= 2.28` : https://fossies.org/linux/coreutils/ChangeLog and `Since version 4.11 of the Linux kernel (April 2017), there's a new statx() system call to retrieve it` : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304779/is-there-still-no-linux-kernel-interface-to-get-file-creation-date  ; https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_4.11#statx.282.29.2C_a_modern_stat.282.29_alternative and also `GNU stat on GNU/Linux systems with glibc 2.28 or above supports it since coreutils 8.31` on the same page. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 66):

@Nux found [a great solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/470135/85695) for this which you should all upvote. I decided to write a little function that can be used to run everything directly. Just add this to your 
`~/.bashrc`.

```bash
get_crtime() {

    for target in "${@}"; do
        inode=$(stat -c '%i' "${target}")
        fs=$(df  --output=source "${target}"  | tail -1)
        crtime=$(sudo debugfs -R 'stat <'"${inode}"'>' "${fs}" 2>/dev/null | 
        grep -oP 'crtime.*--\s*\K.*')
        printf "%s\t%s\n" "${target}" "${crtime}"
    done
}
```

Now, you can run `get_crtime` to print the creation dates of as many files or directories as you like:

```
$ get_crtime foo foo/file 
foo Wed May 21 17:11:08 2014
foo/file    Wed May 21 17:11:27 2014
```

Comment: Note that the creation date is not the creation date of the original file if the file is a copy (like it *is* with the modification date). Once a file is copied, the modification date is from the original, but the creation date is from the copy. (theres is some misunderstanding in this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/529885/how-to-combine-multiple-text-files-into-one-text-file-ordered-by-date-created/529945#529945)

Comment: @JacobVlijm well, yes, of course. Isn't that obvious? How could it be otherwise? A copy is a new file that just happens to have the same contents as another. The modification time also changes for a copy by the way. It is set to the moment the copy was created unless you explicitly choose for that not to happen using `cp -p` or similar.

Comment: Absolutely, but it at the same time, it wouldn't be that unlogical if, like the mod. date, somewhere in the file the date would be stored when it originated. I must admit I didn't know that was not the case until I answered the linked question.

Comment: Just tried by the way, I just copied files in nautilus, modification date stays as it is (was), m. date is earlier than creation date.

Comment: @JacobVlijm ah, so presumably nautilus issues a `cp -p` command. OK, I never use a file manager so I haven't seen that.

Comment: Thanks, that is really new to me, I will remove the answer there.

Comment: I get `df: unrecognized option '--output=source'`

Comment: @demongolem on what OS? What do you get for `df --version` and `man df | grep output`?

Comment: @terdon Oh yeah, I am so used to using Ubuntu, I forgot I am on CentOS 6.7 now.  So `df --version` yields `df (GNU coreutils) 8.4` and `man df | grep output` says `use the POSIX output format output version information and exit`.  The accepted answer does work for perfectly well though with crtime providing me my answer.

Comment: @demongolem yes, the CentOS version of `df` doesn't seem to support the `--output` option. In that case, you can replace that line with `fs=$(df foo | awk '{a=$1}END{print a}'` and the function will work as well. All I'm showing in this answer is a way to wrap the command from the accepted answer in a way that can be run directly for file/directory targets.

Comment: @terdon I see ... Thanks, that does work for me.

Answer (score 20):

The inability of `stat` to show the creation time is due to limitation of the [`stat(2)` system call](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man2/stat.2.html), whose return struct doesn't include a field for the creation time. Starting with Linux 4.11 (i.e., 17.10 and newer*), however, [the new `statx(2)` system call](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man2/statx.2.html) is available, which does include a creation time in its return struct.

<sup><sub>* And possibly on older LTS releases using the hardware enablement stack (HWE) kernels. Check `uname -r` to see if you are using a kernel at least at 4.11 to confirm.</sub></sup>

Unfortunately, it's not easy to call system calls directly in a C program. Typically glibc provides a wrapper that makes the job easy, but glibc only added a wrapper for `statx(2)` in August 2018 (version [2.28](https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2018-08/msg00003.html), available in 18.10). The `stat` command itself gained support for `statx(2)` only in GNU coreutils [8.31 (released in March 2019)](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2019-03/msg00003.html), however, even [Ubuntu 20.04 only has coreutils 8.30](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=coreutils).

But I don't think this will be backported to LTS releases even if they do get, or are already on, newer kernels or glibcs. So, I don't expect `stat` on *any current LTS release* (16.04, 18.04 or 20.04) to ever print the creation time without manual intervention.

On 18.10 and newer, you can directly use the `statx` function as described in [`man 2 statx`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man2/statx.2.html) (note that the 18.10 manpage is incorrect in stating that glibc hasn't added the wrapper yet).

And in Ubuntu 20.10, you will be able to use `stat` directly:

```
# stat --version
stat (GNU coreutils) 8.32
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Michael Meskes.
# stat /
  File: /
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 88h/136d    Inode: 57279593    Links: 1
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2020-08-18 06:57:46.912243164 +0000
Modify: 2020-08-18 06:57:06.768492334 +0000
Change: 2020-08-18 06:57:59.136165661 +0000
 Birth: 2020-08-18 06:57:06.768492334 +0000
```

---

For older systems, luckily, @whotwagner wrote [a sample C program](https://github.com/whotwagner/statx-fun) that shows how to use the `statx(2)` system call on x86 and x86-64 systems. Its output is the same format as `stat`'s default, without any formatting options, but it's simple to modify it to print just the birth time.

First, clone it:

```
git clone https://github.com/whotwagner/statx-fun
```

You can compile the `statx.c` code, or, if you just want the birth time, create a `birth.c` in the cloned directory with the following code (which is a minimal version of `statx.c` printing just the creation timestamp including nanosecond precision):

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _ATFILE_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "statx.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>

// does not (yet) provide a wrapper for the statx() system call
#include <sys/syscall.h>

/* this code works ony with x86 and x86_64 */
#if __x86_64__
#define __NR_statx 332
#else
#define __NR_statx 383
#endif

#define statx(a,b,c,d,e) syscall(__NR_statx,(a),(b),(c),(d),(e))

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int dirfd = AT_FDCWD;
    int flags = AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW;
    unsigned int mask = STATX_ALL;
    struct statx stxbuf;
    long ret = 0;

    int opt = 0;

    while(( opt = getopt(argc, argv, "alfd")) != -1)
    {
        switch(opt) {
            case 'a':
                flags |= AT_NO_AUTOMOUNT;
                break;
            case 'l':
                flags &= ~AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW;
                break;
            case 'f':
                flags &= ~AT_STATX_SYNC_TYPE;
                flags |= AT_STATX_FORCE_SYNC;
                break;
            case 'd':
                flags &= ~AT_STATX_SYNC_TYPE;
                flags |= AT_STATX_DONT_SYNC;
                break;
            default:
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                break;
        }
    }

    if (optind >= argc) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (; optind < argc; optind++) {
        memset(&stxbuf, 0xbf, sizeof(stxbuf));
        ret = statx(dirfd, argv[optind], flags, mask, &stxbuf);
        if( ret < 0)
        {
            perror("statx");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        printf("%lld.%u\n", *&stxbuf.stx_btime.tv_sec, *&stxbuf.stx_btime.tv_nsec);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Then:

```
$ make birth
$ ./birth ./birth.c
1511793291.254337149
$ ./birth ./birth.c | xargs -I {} date -d @{}
Mon Nov 27 14:34:51 UTC 2017
```

In theory this should make the creation time more accessible:

- more filesystems should be supported than just the ext* ones (`debugfs` is a tool for ext2/3/4 filesystems, and unusable on others)
- you don't need root to use this (except for installing some required packages, like `make` and `linux-libc-dev`).

Testing out an xfs system, for example:

```
$ truncate -s 1G temp; mkfs -t xfs temp; mkdir foo; sudo mount temp foo; sudo chown $USER foo
$ touch foo/bar
$ # some time later
$ echo > foo/bar
$ chmod og-w foo/bar
$ ./birth foo/bar | xargs -I {} date -d @{}
Mon Nov 27 14:43:21 UTC 2017
$ stat foo/bar                             
  File: foo/bar
  Size: 1           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 700h/1792d  Inode: 99          Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ muru)      Gid: ( 1000/ muru)
Access: 2017-11-27 14:43:32.845579010 +0000
Modify: 2017-11-27 14:44:38.809696644 +0000
Change: 2017-11-27 14:44:45.536112317 +0000
 Birth: -
```

However, this didn't work for NTFS and exfat. I guess the FUSE filesystems for those didn't include the creation time.

Comment: Thanks for linking to github. I searched a few months ago when 4.11 came out and didn't find anything and then forgot about it.

Comment: Now that the feature is available, would you know how to modify that field?  I may try to create a ctypes wrapper to do it in python.  Thanks.

Comment: Nice answer! It would be nice to see this get incorporated into a standard tool (ideally stat itself).

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR:**
Just run:
`sudo debugfs -R 'stat /path/to/your/file' /dev/<your fs>`

(To figure out your fs, run `df -T /path/to/your/file`, most likely it's going to be `/dev/sda1`).

**Long version:**

We are going to run two commands:

1. Find out the name of partition name for your file.

   ```bash
   df -T /path/to/your/file
   ```

   The output is going to look like this (partition name is first):

   ```
   Filesystem     Type 1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
   /dev/<your fs> ext4   7251432 3481272   3509836  50% /
   ```
2. Find out creation time for that file.

   ```
   sudo debugfs -R 'stat /path/to/your/file' /dev/<your fs>
   ```

   In the output, look for `ctime`.

Answer (score 4):

My OS (Ubuntu 20.04, which comes with Linux kernel 5.4.0-28 and GLIBC 2.31) only came with GNU coreutils 8.30, so I had to get it to work by [compiling version 8.32 of GNU coreutils from source](https://duntuk.com/how-upgrade-coreutils-latest-version-source?PageSpeed=noscript). It was a relatively pain-free procedure.

Afterwards, both `ls` and `stat` could work with birth time.

Output of `ls -l --time=birth --time-style=full-iso --no-group`:
[image: ls with birth time]

Output of `stat` on an ext4 file system and a btrfs file system:
[image: stat with birth time]

(Copied from [my other answer on UNIX & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/583457/64370))

Comment: hmmm well it does do all that ie shows you "birth:" on 20.04 if you upgrade to coreutils_8.32-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb and libselinux1_3.1-2_amd64.deb
but then it wipes out huge amounts of :i386 files and totally disables wine on my system so maybe to warn folks that it does do that [prob 200 files on my system] as it is quite a heavy price to pay :]  basically it broke my set up here and had to track back to original setup

Answer (score 0):

You may need the file creation time in human readable but not standard format to use in bash shell script pipeline. For example, to prefixing the file name for appropriate sorting in the file manager. I modified @terdon solution for this purpose as following.

```
get_crtime() {

    for target in "${@}"; do
        inode=$(stat -c '%i' "${target}")
        fs=$(df  --output=source "${target}"  | tail -1)
        crtime=$(sudo debugfs -R 'stat <'"${inode}"'>' "${fs}" 2>/dev/null |
        grep -oP 'crtime.*--\s*\K.*')
        printf $(date -d "${crtime}" | sed 's/://g'| sed 's/-//g')
    done
}
```

- `date -d ...` parses date time string;
- `sed` removes special characters `:` and `-`;
- no end of line added.

Which produses:

```
get_crtime .bashrc
20201023T181422
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried yours and got just "Tue".