# How to stop Ubuntu 14.04 from changing timestamp on cut and paste?

Tags: nautilus

When I 'Move' pictures from my camera or phone into Ubuntu using 'Files V3.10.1', the timestamp in the 'Modified' column changes to the day I move the files.
Obviously I did not 'modify' the file, I just moved it onto my computer, so if I import a picture i took a month ago it will sit in line with pictures I took today.

1. Is there a way to stop this and keep the timestamp of when the
   picture was taken?
2. Is there a way to show the 'Created' column in "Files 3.10.1" ?

Comment: And for the other question: `ext4` for example stores the creation time of files / folders, but there's no implemented function in the kernel to access them (nor a function implemented in Files that I know of; maybe one can be crafted by modifying and recompiling Files, but that's obviously not a trivial task). So the problem with the creation time is at the roots. [There are tools capable of extracting the creation time of inodes](http://askubuntu.com/a/470135/380067), but their implementation is limited to the command line AFAIK.