# What file search tool can be used to track files based on creation date?

Tags: search, ubuntu-mate

I am using Ubuntu (MATE) 16.04.

I am looking for a GUI search tool to search by creation date. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

I've tried:

- MATE search tool - can only search by modified date, by using "Date modified less than" / "...greater than"
- Tracker ("Desktop search") will only permit keyword search (on file names or content).
- Recoll only indicates "file date" search, which matches modification date only.

None of the above can show the creation date in search results (column fields can't be added).

I'd appreciate any suggestions.
Is there a too

Comment: In the first place, the creation date is not easily available on anything except [the most recent Linux kernels](https://askubuntu.com/a/918303/158442). And even then userland hasn't caught up yet.

Comment: In order to get creation time you need both a filesystem that stores it and a kernel that provides an API for it: see [How to find creation date of file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91200/65304)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try search functionality of

[Krusader](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/extragear-utils/krusader/krusearcher.html) (`sudo apt-get install krusader`)
or
[DoubleCommander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/site/eng/index.html) (`sudo apt-get install doublecmd-gtk`).