# New STATX: how do I find the creation time (birth time) of a file?

Tags: stat

How to use the new `statx` function to get only one information: the creation time (birth time) of a file.

I have tried in terminal command line without success.

Comment: P.S.: I tagged this question on stat tag because I have not enough points to create the new correct tag: statx (appreciate if someone tag it correctly)

Comment: See my answer there: https://askubuntu.com/a/980750/158442

Comment: I have seen your answer on that link. Is not possible to have a simpler solution? I mean the question is simple: how to use `statx` to get a creation date of a file. Do we really need all that for this simple task?

Comment: Until a wrapper gets added to glibc or someone published a one-off command just for this on Ubuntu, yes. And the statement of a question being simple has little to no relation with the simplicity of the answer.

Comment: `stat` now prints birth time, you need glibc >= 2.28 and coreutils >= 8.31